# Home and logout button do not work until page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 buttons on my header, one for home & one for logout. Both buttons appear. However, they do not work unless i refresh the page. Attached are my codes. The buttons work on the home page but not on the other redirected pages.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnLogout").bind("click", function () {
        window.location = "login.html";
    });

    $("#btnHome").bind("click", function () {
        window.location = "home.html";
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="button" id="btnHome" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left" value="Home" />
    <input type="button" id="btnLogout" class="ui-btn-right" value="Logout" />
</div>
```

Please help! Do let me know if there's anything else you need to know

Comment: I see you have changed the onload to onready. When I paste it into a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/5medfrbb/6/) it works for me. Does it still not work for you? Is there any other code you have not yet provided?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put these clicks within a windows on load? When you put the scripts tag just before the `</body>` the on on.load (in this case) is not necessary. Try to remove this function and check the results like so:

```
$("#btnLogout").bind("click", function () {
    window.location = "login.html";
});

$("#btnHome").bind("click", function () {
    window.location = "home.html";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The load function is not working. Use `$(window).ready(function())` instead.

```
$(window).ready(function() {

    $("#btnLogout").bind("click", function () {
        window.location = "login.html";
    });

    $("#btnHome").bind("click", function () {
        window.location = "home.html";
    });
});
```

Comment: To be honest, I do not know why it is not working either. I have just tried using on ready instead of on load and it worked.

Comment: it is because the question is not clear, not enough info

Comment: When i first get redirected into the page and press the buttons, nothing happens. But when i refresh it, the buttons are able to work.

Answer (score 0):

If your button is generate dynamically you can access direct `DOM` with document method.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click","#btnLogout", function () {
        alert(1)
        //window.location = "login.html";
    });

    $(document).on("click","#btnHome", function () {
        alert(2)
        //window.location = "home.html";
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="button" id="btnHome" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left" value="Home" />
    <input type="button" id="btnLogout" class="ui-btn-right" value="Logout" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

this load function is wrong `$(window).on("load", function () {` you can add ready functin`$(window).ready(function() {`

```
$(window).ready(function() {

    $("#btnLogout").bind("click", function () {
        window.location = "login.html";
    });

    $("#btnHome").bind("click", function () {
        window.location = "home.html";
    });
});
```

you try this code

Comment: Your answer does not address the issue properly. Reasons: 1) the problem is not due to the windows event trigger; 2) you did not provide further helpful information.

Answer (score -1):

First, it is perfectly fine to use bind method inside windows on load event. BUT, it is DEPRECATED in JQuery version 3.0! So, it is very likely you are using an incompatible version.

Instead, you should use:

```
$("#btnLogout").on("click", function () {
  window.location = "login.html";
});

$("#btnHome").on("click", function () {
  window.location = "home.html";
});
```

As you can see, the syntax is pretty much alike.

Check out my running code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/caiubyfreitas/fkf72xau/):

:)